# Storybook customization

Tags: frontend, icons, customization, storybook

There is a way to customize my Storybook UI? I want to change all the default icons with my custom icons. I know that is possible to add some custom themes but I want to know if is possible to change, for example, from the booked icon to my custom icon.

I'm using Storybook HTML 6.5.16